# newman fails to run on Centos 6.6, apparently due to jsdom/contextify issue

Tags: node.js, centos6

I've installed newman (https://github.com/a85/Newman) on a CentOS 6.6 box and although the installation appears to succeed, trying to run `newman --version` results in the following:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:91
  throw err
        ^
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/contextify.node
 → /usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/Debug/contextify.node
 → /usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/Release/contextify.node
 → /usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/out/Debug/contextify.node
 → /usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/Debug/contextify.node
 → /usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/out/Release/contextify.node
 → /usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/Release/contextify.node
 → /usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/default/contextify.node
 → /usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/compiled/0.10.33/linux/x64/contextify.node
    at bindings (/usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:1:96)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:5:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I've Googled this to death and found a few claimed solutions, but nothing seems to work. It looks like the problem is ultimately with jsdom and it's dependency contextify. What's strange is that the file that it can't find (`contextify.node`), does actually exist at one of the paths it claims to be checking.